# compilation error in C pointer working in 32 bits, not in 64 bits

Tags: c

I am trying to compile a c program in 64 bits. It is already working in 32 bits for several years and used by some clients.

Example of code working in 32 bits :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char* rcfilename ;
    char* vhome ;
    char* script = "/script/main.tcl" ;

    vhome = (char *)getenv("VHOME");
    rcfilename = (char *) malloc(strlen(vhome) + strlen(script) + 1) ;

    strcpy(rcfilename, vhome) ;
    return 0;
}
```

in Compil in 64 bits  i have an error:

> conversion between a pointer and an integer of different size

and a segmentation fault in execution.

I have no experience in pointer in c, so i prefer to ask for help !

Comment: At which line ? And at which lines does it crash?

Comment: You seem to be missing headers, `#include <stdlib.h>` for both `malloc()` and `getenv()`. Otherwise default-`int` will bite you when `sizeof (int) != sizeof (void *)`.

Comment: vhome = (char *)getenv("VHOME"); is already  crashing in 64 bits

Comment: Please post a [MCVE], I'm not sure how the code you show here can produce that warning. I suspect the code you show here is not the code you compile. We've seen this often enough here.

Comment: #include <stdlib.h> seems  a good response at first look . . but why it is not obligatory in 32 bits ?

Comment: BTW the crash is certainly due to the fact that `getenv("VHOME")` returns `NULL` for some reason. Check that.

Comment: @MichaelWalz The crash might as well be caused by only 32 bits of the pointer returned by `getenv` being assigned to `vhome`. I place my bet on unwind's explanation in this case.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck yes you're certainly right. But the return value of `getenv` should be checked anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, you should:

- include the proper headers (stdlib.h and string.h)
- check for the value return, in particular the getenv call:

  ```
  if (!(vhome = (char *)getenv("VHOME"))){
      fprintf(stderr, "getenv(\"VHOME\") returned NULL\n");
      return -1;
  }
  ```